# Missing all header files in CocoaPods for GoogleMaps.framework after checkout from SVN repo

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, cocoapods

I am Integrating Google map in my app by using Cocoapods. Cocoapds installed successfully in my Project which I created locally in my machine, and showing  GoogleMaps.framework and its all header files in that. After that I had compressed (zipped) my project and given to other member for import to SVN repo, and he had import project from windows machine. Now when I checked out Project and build and Run then I got following build error. I had resolved it by using terminal command ‘pod install’

PhaseScriptExecution Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/sw.sal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPro-hfgbmtnudtrrqtbghtzkgaueuugm/Build/Intermediates/MyPro.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyPro.build/Script-B728B15E1844D49B5CB2A981.sh
    cd "/Users/sw.sal/Documents/My Project/Vi P/Project/SVN Project"
    /bin/sh -c /Users/sw.sal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPro-hfgbmtnudtrrqtbghtzkgaueuugm/Build/Intermediates/MyPro.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyPro.build/Script-B728B15E1844D49B5CB2A981.sh

/Users/sw.sal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPro-hfgbmtnudtrrqtbghtzkgaueuugm/Build/Intermediates/MyPro.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyPro.build/Script-B728B15E1844D49B5CB2A981.sh: line 2: /Users/sw.sal/Documents/My Project/Vi P/Project/SVN Project/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyPro/Pods-MyPro-frameworks.sh: Permission denied

But Now I got this in my Project that it builds successfully but missing all header files in Pods->GoogleMaps.framework. I had attached the screen shot also.

Please someone guide me how I can Integrate all frameworks with all header files in Cocoapods after checkout Project from SVN.[image: missing all header files from framewirk screenshot]